# Why Products Export Magento 1 breaks?

Tags: magento-1.9, export

I'm in the need to export from Magento 1 customers and products.
To import them back on a new Magento 2 shop.

I'm following this guide:
https://www.mag-manager.com/product-information/magento-product-management/how-to-transfer-products-from-magento-1-to-magento-2/

But when I launch export for products, after 30-40" processing, page stops 
printing out the error:

Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in /opt/lampp/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Entity/Product.php on line 948

Any idea on how to overcome this error, or any other approach suggestion is welcome.

Comment: This looks like a 3rd party Store Manager tool, did you purchase it?  I suggest you please update the post (and title) indicating this if this is the case so someone may assist.  The article seems to only focus on _products_ only.  
To migrate everything, from attributes, customers, etc you would need to use the [**Magento Data Migration Tool**](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/migration-tool.html).  
This tool targets all database tables, and try to migrate into Magento 2 installation. You need to setup the XML target columns though; for 3rd party M1 module data.

Comment: What makes you think there's a 3rd party tool involved?

Comment: The article only seem to discuss **products exportation**.  How do you transfer Attributes, Email Templates, Customers, Categories?  
**Quoted from that page:**   
"If you need to transfer Magento 1 customers, orders, attribute sets, custom options, > cart price rules or abandoned carts to Magento 2, Store Manager can assist you with > it in a very suitable manner."

Comment: Thanks for all other hints you're providing. But the point of the question is exporting products from Magento 1. It breaks. And it happens from the admin panel, export section just like described in that article. I'd like to understand why... Since it should be straight forward having my products csv file for products.

Comment: No problem, I was just suggesting to use the Magento Data Migration Tool because it targets all database tables directly. (You confirmed you did not purchase the tool - the start of the discussion.) Atm you are getting stuck with step 1 already (products).  I have also previously attempted exports using the same method - it never works reliably, especially if you have to redo it so many times (restarts etc).  I cannot help with this further, just advising that after you do that - then you have customers, etc. 100s of M1 tables to migrate.  Just advising there might be better way migrating. Gl!